# Looking for a trigonometric function with known shape

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a trigonometric function where I know the shape of
and also have some function values.

I almost have it but my formula is not precise.
If you plot

$$\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\sin 3t - \frac{3}{4}\cos 6t$$ you see the shape I have in mind.
As you see the graph starts with a tiny interval with negative function
values : thats my problem.
The value $1$ at $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$ and the value $2$ at $\pi/2$ is OK.

But the curve should have this shape with non-negative image.
It should have zeros at $2\pi/6$ and $4\pi$.

Is there a method to tackle this problem ?

Does anyone have a (way of) solution for it ?

Comment: Hope this helps. cos 6t = 1 - 2 (sin 3t)^2. Your expression will then become a quadratic in sin 3t.

Comment: Sorry, this is a trigonometric identity and doesnt change the shape of the curve to the similar one I am looking for with f(t)>=0.